# Android wake screen from service

Tags: android, service, wakelock

I have a service running which receives events. When an event is received I need the service to wake up the screen and run an activity.

Currently, it's working using `wakeLock` parameters:

```
PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP)
```

I use this to wake the screen before starting the activity. The activity also has flags:

```
getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

However, `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` and `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` are deprecated. I want to know what's the alternative to using wake lock? I haven't been able to get it work without using wake lock.

Answer (score 0):

You could add [FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON) to your window flags.

> when set as a window is being added or made visible, once the window has been shown then the system will poke the power manager's user activity (as if the user had woken up the device) to turn the screen on.

This way your activity will wake the screen automatically when you start it from your service, eliminating the need for a wakelock.